# Dynamic variable onchange of dropdown including PHP that allows to connect to multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, connection

I need to connect to a database but it seems that it refuses the AJAX request.
What I want it to do is when an option is chosen, it will send it to connect.php so that the database can connect.

The error I get is `"You have not selected a database"` the `$database` doesn't set before the connection is made. So it returns that error. Since if I set the database to test then it connects but only to that selected database that I hard coded into the connect.php file.

This is my head where the AJAX and javascript is:

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" 
href="http://www.iconj.com/ico/t/w/tw971ajo31.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeDatabase()
{
    var selname = $("#database option:selected").val();  
    $.ajax({ url: "login.php",
        data: {"selname":selname},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {

            $("#own").html(output);

            $.ajax({
              data: {database: output},
              url: "connect.php"
           });
        }

       });
}
window.onload =  changeDatabase();
</script>
```

This is where the dropdown list is being populated:

```
<form>
    <select name="database" id="database" onchange="changeDatabase();">
          <?php
               $sql="SELECT client_code,company_name FROM `propworx_shared_data`.client_info  WHERE `client_info`.active = 1 ORDER BY company_name ASC" ;
        $result =mysql_query($sql);

        while ($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $client_code = $rows['client_code'];
            $company_name = $rows['company_name'];
            echo  '<option value="'.$client_code.'">'.$company_name.'</option>';
         } 
             echo 'database';
         ?>
         </select>
         </form>
```

These are all php webpages.
This is the connect.php where the connection is.

```
<?php 
$connect_error = 'Sorry we are down for maintainence';
$link = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die($connect_error);

        $database = $_GET['database']; //This alwast seems to be undefined.

    mysql_select_db($database, $link);

?>
```